# Azure web site - How to get server error details (truncated trace file)

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm using Azure Web API 2.  My clients are getting some 500 errors, and I'm trying to figure out why.  I've turned on tracing in Azure portal, and without a truncated file, I see some great info like:

```
235. - GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER 
{"Message":...,"ExceptionMessage"...,"StackTrace":".....
```

The problem is my log files are getting truncated at 1MB.  (The amount of posted JSON data can be large, which eats up log space.)

I see some potentially nice .htm files in LogFiles/DetailedErrors, but they are generic pages without any details or trace info.

In Web.Config I set `<customErrors mode="Off" />`.  This added detail to trace files, but not to the DetailedErrors htm files.

Questions:

1) Can I increase the max size of the trace file?  (I tried unsuccessfully using maxLogFileSizeKB, but didn't know where to put it, presumably in Web.Config.)

2) Any other way to see stack trace information on server errors from the LogFiles directory on the server, or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be logging to the wrong place. There's three different places to store the logs, but the Preview Portal makes this less clear than the old Azure Portal. The documentation for logging still directs you to the old portal to set up and you can log to Blob Storage or to Table Storage.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/. Logging to tables might be less limiting.

Comment: Hi Amanda.  Thank you for your response.  I read the link and tried using the old portal and sending logs to blob storage, and while I did get a log, it wasn't at a detail level.  I never found trace files on blob storage.  I'm trying a new approach... creating an IExceptionLogger so I can be notified of unhandled errors and perform my own logging.  I'm hoping this will solve my problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to increase the log size, I was able to get the trace information with `IExceptionLogger`.  I don't need any special error handling, so just being notified is good enough for me.  This is for API (2) controllers.

1) In App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs, I added the following line

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ApiErrorLogger());
```

2) Create my `ApiErrorLogger` class

```
public class ApiErrorLogger : ExceptionLogger {

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context) {
        addLogError(context.Request.RequestUri.ToString(), context.Exception.Message, context.Exception.StackTrace);
    }

    public static void addLogError(string uri, string message, string stackTrace) {
        // Store data in Azure table
    }
}
```

I don't have to use `<customErrors mode="Off" />`, which is good, and I can turn tracing off (which is resource expensive) in Azure portal.